# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter when starting Simple Struts2 Application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, struts2

I am trying to run a simple Struts2 application but it always throw the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

I have followed the step by step tutorial in [Create Struts 2 Web Application Using Maven To Manage Artifacts and To Build The Application](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html#create-struts-2-web-application-using-maven-to-manage-artifacts-and-to-build-the-application), but I cannot make it work.

I also managed to find other Struts2 tutorial which uses maven but all failed. It throws the same exception when I try to run the application.

I used the following:

- Eclipse
- Maven
- Tomcat
- Struts2

According to other discussions, the dependencies jar files(e.g. struts2-core) must be put on the lib folder but as for me, I am using Maven so all the dependencies are already included in my build path under Maven Dependencies.

I even tried running the sample project given in Struts2 website ([Basic_Struts_2_Maven_2_3_1_2.zip](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-examples/downloads/detail?name=Basic_Struts_2_Maven_2_3_1_2.zip&can=2&q=)) but I still have no luck. Building it is successful but running it on server always fail.

Am I missing anything?

**Here's the `web.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Basic_Struts2_Maven</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**`pom.xml`:**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>manning</groupId>
    <artifactId>Basic_Struts2_Mvn</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Basic Struts 2</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>Basic_Struts2_Mvn</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <package name="basicstruts2" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="index">
                <result>/index.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

**`.classpath`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: did yop added jar files to classpath

Comment: can you show web.xml pls

Comment: libraries should be in the WEB-INF/lib

Comment: @RomanC Would it be okay to have the jars declared twice in my build path? It's already in my build path under Maven Dependencies right now. If I put it in my lib folder, it would have another entry in my build path.

Comment: @PSR When I looked in my .classpath, it has an entry `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
  <attributes>
   <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
  </attributes>
 </classpathentry>` .Should I put another entry for each of the dependencies?

Comment: @vida try to put we will check where the problem is

Comment: @vida they should be there in the war after build. Also post the `struts.xml`.

Comment: @RomanC yes, when I extracted the war file, all jar files are inside WEB_INF/lib folder

Comment: @PSR Added all jar files in .classpath file but got the same result. Here's a sample of the classpath entry I added: `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/vida/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.1.6/struts2-core-2.1.6.jar"/>` . All entries point to the dependecies' same location on my local maven repository.

Comment: @vida you have wrong version, remove this entry. Post  `.classpath`.

Comment: @vida So, what run away?

Comment: @RomanC I tried to change the version and the classpath entries. Still the same result.

Comment: @vida do you deploy from Eclipse? If so try to build war from cmd and then deploy it to tomcat - without Eclipse

Comment: @LukaszLenart That's how developer work, trying everything possible and impossible spending enormous value of time trying to make it working until it becomes working.

Comment: @LukaszLenart I just built it using command line. For some weird reason I still don't understand, it worked. :| So what's the real issue here?Does this mean that maven plugin for eclipse could possibly be the problem?

Comment: @vida yep, try what RomanC suggested below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this command to convert Maven project to Dynamic Web Project for Eclipse:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=3.4.2
```

you may change whatever WTP version you use

`.classpath` should be like this

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/asm/asm/3.3/asm-3.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/asm/asm-commons/3.3/asm-commons-3.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/asm/asm-tree/3.3/asm-tree-3.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2.2/commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar" />
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/commons-lang-2.5.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.18/freemarker-2.3.18.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javassist/javassist/3.11.0.GA/javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/ognl/ognl/3.0.4/ognl-3.0.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.3.1.2/struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/lib/tools.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/struts/xwork/xwork-core/2.3.1.2/xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
</classpath>
```

After build the WAR file should deploy to `%CATALINA_BASE%\webapps`.

Comment: I am currently using a maven plugin for eclipse. I believe it configures the project so that it will run on Eclipse.

Comment: Did you try to do what I suggested?

Comment: @vida Eclipse Maven support is... crapy ;-)

Comment: @RomanC yup. I edited my .classpath file. It worked when using a command line :)

Answer (score 2):

Dear this the part of Struts 2 Core 2.2.3.1 API.

And I tried to run you linked project it is properly working for me. there is no issue.

Comment: I've tried both the latest (2.3.12) and some of the other older versions but none of it worked so far.

Comment: As I told you the link you share is perfectly working you need to cross check you project for it.

Comment: May I know the versions of your Eclipse, Tomcat and Maven? Are you using a maven plugin for Eclipse or a stand alone maven? Thank you very much.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno and eclipse maven plugin (maven 2) and tomcat 6

Comment: I'm using m2e. It's the same as yours, I guess. I just used command line instead. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I think you specified like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>X.X.X.X</version>
</dependency>
```

try to add

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
     <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @vida try to add the dependency i spwcified and let me know problem is solved or not

Comment: Why not to use latest Struts2 version.

Comment: @Aleksandr M no problem we can use.But to know the problem i gave that code.I have previously used that code