# Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Tags: struts2

I just started learning struts2 when I am trying to deploy to tomcat I am encountering the following error

```
Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

I went through couple of other posts but I am unable to resolve the issue please help me.. 
Thanks much !

/***here is the web.xml file I am using***/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Struts2Start</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

/**Struts.xml**/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="getTutorial" class="com.javabrains.struts.action.TutorialAction">
      <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
      <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

/***console***/

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.18.jar
ognl-3.0.4.jar
struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar
xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220862/classnotfoundexception-strutsprepareandexecutefilter-in-struts2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15545326/573032

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I figured out my problem was that I forgot to export my user defined libraries, in this case, struts libraries. You can export the libraries via Eclipse by

1. Go to the Markers tab (If you can't see, do Windows > Show View > Markers)
2. Expand "Classpath Dependency Validator Message"
3. Right click "Classpath entry org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/struts2 will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result."
4. Click "Quick Fix"
5. Select "Mark the associated raw classpath entry as a publish/export dependency."
6. click "Finish"

Answer (score 3):

There could be some reasons to get this error. One of the reason can be the version of jar you use does not have the required class. Check `struts2-core-X.X.X.X.jar`, and make sure that it contains `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` class under `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter` package.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following jars and remove all others.

- commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
- commons-io-2.0.1.jar
- commons-lang3-3.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- freemarker-2.3.19.jar
- javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
- ognl-3.0.6.jar
- struts2-core-2.3.15.1.jar
- xwork-core-2.3.15.1.jar

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I was able to solve it by adding a few more jar files. You must have at least the following jar files:

1. commons-fileupload-X.X.X.jar
2. commons-io-X.X.jar
3. commons-lang-X.X.jar
4. commons-logging-X.X.X.jar
5. commons-logging-api-X.X.jar
6. commons-lang3-X.X.jar
7. freemaker-X.X.X.jar
8. javassist-X.X.X.GA.jar
9. ognl-X.X.X.jar
10. struts2-core-X.X.X.X.jar
11. xwork-core-X.X.X.X.jar